# useEffect not producing data in console.log in sequence

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

i am a begginer to react i am learning the useEffect hook currently i am a little bit confused over the sequence at which the data in console.log is printed , please explain it in steps , thanks

**initailly i see b and c printed but then i see a ,b ,c after each second why is that ?**
**code**

```
 const [count, setCount] = useState(0);


 const tick = () => {

   setCount(count + 1)
 }

 useEffect(() => {
   console.log("b")

   const intervel = setInterval(tick, 1000)

   console.log("c")
   return () => {
     console.log("a")
     clearInterval(intervel)

   }
 }, [count]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you are returning at the end of `useEffect()`

```
return () => {
     console.log("a")
     clearInterval(intervel)
   }
```

is not run the first time the component renders. That is called a cleanup function. You are **returning** that anonymous function to the top of the execution queue on the next render.

Knowing that, we can see that your render cycle will look something like this

**Render 1**:

console.log("b")

wait 1 second

console.log("c")

return console.log("a") to next render

**Render 2**:

console.log("a")

console.log("b")

wait 1 second

console.log("c")

return console.log("a") to next render

Comment: thanks a lot maan , also i dont't think there will be one second wait  for b or c but there will be wait one second wait and then the useEffect runs again  because its setInterval(tick,1000)  it will call tick function after 1 second which increase the count by 1 ,  i am not sure but i think its like that , share anything if you knoq , again thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The function inside which you print `a` is called a cleanup function.
React calls that function **before applying the next effects**. That is why you see afterwards `a` printed each time `count` is changed. It is a cleanup being called from the previous render before applying effect for this render.  From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1):

> When exactly does React clean up an effect? React performs the cleanup
> when the component unmounts. However, as we learned earlier, effects
> run for every render<sup>1</sup> and not just once. This is why React also cleans
> up effects from the previous render before running the effects next
> time. We’ll discuss why this helps avoid bugs and how to opt out of
> this behavior in case it creates performance issues later below.

---

<sup>1</sup> That part of docs didn't talk about dependencies yet, hence it mentions effects running on each render.

Answer (score 0):

you set that useEffect depend on [count]

it means that you ask useEffect to recall everytime count change and call returned function (

```
return ()=>{
console.log("a")
clearInterval(intervel)

}
```

) after count change so

first component render
after render useEffect call this function

```
   console.log("b")

   const intervel = setInterval(tick, 1000)

   console.log("c")
```

but tick change count every 1s and useEffect depend on it so after 1s
useEffect will clear because count changed so interval will stop

and will call again
so it will create a new interval and start again again again